# What's the difference between home_url() and site_url()

Tags: functions, urls, site-url, home-url

My understanding is that `site_url()` returns the location where the WordPress core files are.

If my blog is hosted at `http://example.com/blog` then `site_url()` returns `http://example.com/blog`

But then how does `home_url()` differ? For me, `home_url()` returns the same thing: `http://example.com/blog`

If that's correct, then can I get WordPress to return `http://example.com/` ?

Comment: You're asking two questions at once on a very important question. The answer to "What's the difference between home_url() and site_url()?" is different than the question, "How do I get WordPress to return the URL root without the subdirectory where it's installed?"

Comment: Review these codex guides: https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29 ; https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Blog_address_.28URL.29 ; http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You are asking two questions at once:

1. What's the difference between `home_url()` and `site_url()`?
2. How do I get WordPress to return the URL root without the subdirectory where it's installed?

Here are the answers, and I confirmed with Andrew Nacin, a core developer of WordPress, as well as ran some server tests to confirm what Andrew told me.

### Question # 1

In General > Settings of wp-admin, `home_url()` references the field labeled "Site Address (URL)". *Confusing, huh?* Yeah, it says "Site Address" so you might assume `site_url()`, but **you'd be wrong**. Run your own test and you'll see. (You can temporarily drop an `echo H1` field with `site_url()` and `home_url()` values at the top of your your theme's functions.php.)

Meanwhile, `site_url()` references the field labeled "WordPress Address (URL)" in General > Settings.

So, if you're wanting to reference where a physical path might be such as calling a plugin's folder path on the URL to load an image, or calling a theme's folder path to load an image, you should actually use other functions for those - look at `plugins_url()` and `get_template_directory_uri()`.

The `site_url()` will always be the location where you can reach the site by tacking on `/wp-admin` on the end, while `home_url()` would not reliably be this location.

The `home_url()` would be where you have set your homepage by setting General > Settings "Site Address (URL)" field.

### Question # 2

So, if I have placed my blog in `http://example.com/blog`, and `example.com` is just some static site where I have like a portfolio theme, then this would be a scenario that lines up with your question. In such a case, then I would use this snippet of code:

```
<?php
function getDomain() {
    $sURL    = site_url(); // WordPress function
    $asParts = parse_url( $sURL ); // PHP function

    if ( ! $asParts )
      wp_die( 'ERROR: Path corrupt for parsing.' ); // replace this with a better error result

    $sScheme = $asParts['scheme'];
    $nPort   = $asParts['port'];
    $sHost   = $asParts['host'];
    $nPort   = 80 == $nPort ? '' : $nPort;
    $nPort   = 'https' == $sScheme AND 443 == $nPort ? '' : $nPort;
    $sPort   = ! empty( $nPort ) ? ":$nPort" : '';
    $sReturn = $sScheme . '://' . $sHost . $sPort;

    return $sReturn;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the discussion with A.Nacin?

Comment: It was via email. Sorry. Oh, and thanks for the edit -- I'll remember that syntax change next time.

Comment: It took me a very long time and a lot of pain to realize that 'Site Address (URL)' = 'home' and 'WordPress Address (URL)' = 'siteurl'. They should definitely change those labels.

Comment: Your answer to the second question hits the jackpot!

Comment: It seems there is a typo in `$sPort = ! empty( $sPort ) ? ":$nPort" : '';`. I think `! empty( $sPort )` should be `! empty( $nPort )`. Otherwise, `":$nPort"` will never be reached, hence `$sPort = ''` and a port will never be appended to the third last line.

Comment: @Ferris you are correct and I edited it. Thanks.

Answer (score 33):

##**TLDR:**
In a non-standard installation, you can place your WordPress files in a subdirectory of your website root.
...and still allow your visitors to visitors to access your WordPress "website" from your site's Domain (root) URL, *without appending the subdirectory name:*
(ie: `www.example.com` vs `www.example.com/wordpress`):

```
WP function  | wp_options. | WP constant  | what it represents       | WP Settings Label | Example     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
`site_url()` | `siteurl`   | `WP_SITEURL` | WordPress files location | WordPress Address | https://www.example.com/wordpress
`home_url()` | `home`      | `WP_HOME`    | browser address bar      | Site Address      | https://www.example.com
```

Where the value for a WP constant takes precedence over an wp_options/ WP Settings value.

##Different Configurations for WordPress

In the most *standard* WordPress installations, `home_url` and `site_url` will have the same value.
Regardless, they represent two different things.

In a *non-standard* installation, they may have different values.

> **NOTE:** I am leaving off the protocol in my answer for easier readability.
> In this post, PREPEND EVERY URL with:
> `https://`, `http://` OR `//`
> (unless I included it already).

*(`//` is the `relative` protocol and will work for either/both `http://` or `https://`)*

#### Standard Installations (including "One-Click" Installs)

`home_url`: is the home page of your (wordpress) website, as indicated in the user's address bar.
`site_url`: is the directory where your wordpress files are located.

WordPress's 5-minute install installs wordpress files these two values will be the same - wordpress files will be installed in the same folder that you want people to use to address your website, or the wordpress (blog) portion of your server's website.

**Example 1:**
user accesses your blog at: `www.example.com`,
wordpress files installed at: `www.example.com`, or the root folder of your server's website.

`home_url` === `site_url` === `"www.example.com"`

**Example 2:**
user accesses your blog at: `www.example.com/blog`,
wordpress files installed at: `www.example.com/blog`, or in the `blog` folder inside the root of your website.

`home_url` === `site_url` === `"www.example.com/blog"`

In this case `www.example.com` is the main website, and `www.example.com/blog` is the root of your blog.
Here your blog is separated from, and works as subset of, your main website.
In this case, your main website is *not* controlled, defined, or styled by WordPress.
Just your blog is.  All urls in your blog will be proceeded by `www.example.com/blog`

*Note: In documentation, "Wordpress site/website" (as opposed to simply "site/website") refers to the directory where your WordPress files are installed. In this case, it is `www.example.com/blog` - everything within the `blog` folder.  The "WordPress website", in this scenario, is not the same as your domain, your root, or your main website.  It is a subset of your overall website.  Kind of like a website inside a website.  I mention this as the terminology can seem unclear or confusing, given this particular setup.*

#### Alternate WordPress Installation Configuration

[Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/), the section `Method II (With URL change)`.

For example, many people don't want to clog up the root folder of their website with all the wordpress files.
They want to install wordpress in a subdirectory, *but have the "blog" or "WordPress website" accessed *as if* the files were installed in the root of the server's root for the website.

This is particularly be true when WordPress is used to build and run an entire website that does not even have a "blog".

**Example 3:**
user accesses your "blog" at: `www.example.com`,
wordpress files installed at: `www.example.com/wordpress`, or the root folder of your server's website.

`home_url` === `"www.example.com"`
`site_url` === `"www.example.com/wordpress"`

*(Note: this configuration will not work "out of the box" just by changing the values of these variables.  It requires additional configuration changes to work properly)*
See [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/), the section titled `Method II (With URL change)` for how to do this.

In *this* case `home_url` and `site_url` should hold different values.

In this setup, you want your website to **function** exactly ***as if*** WordPress files were installed in the server's root directory for your website...
BUT, for organizational purposes on the server,
you ***actually*** have your WordPress files in a folder called `wordpress` in the server's root directory for your website.

So, user will type in `www.example.com` to get your WordPress home page, instead of `www.example.com/wordpress`

#### wordpress function <--> database variable <--> Wordpress Constant

> This section assumes Example 3 configuration above.
> address bar url: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
> wordpress files: /wordpress directory

*(The other cases are trivial: All variables/functions hold/return the same value.)*

##### How to set the values for `site_url` and `home_url`

First, let me note that `siteurl` and `home` store values returned by the functions above

1. Normally you set these values on the WordPress backend/dashboard/admin panel:
   `Settings -> General ->`
   `siteurl`  WordPress Address:  `https://www.example.com/wordpress`
   `home`  Site Address:       `https://www.example.com`

*(do not include trailing slashes here - that would be configured elsewhere)*

2. Alternatively, you set these values in your WordPress database:
   `wp_options` table ->

   ### `options_name` | `options_value`

   `siteurl`      | `https://www.example.com/wordpress`
   `home`         | `https://www.example.com`

*(do not include trailing slashes here - that would be configured elsewhere)*

3. Edit your `wp-config.php`
   Define **these specific constants** to hold your values
   Define `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` settings by inserting these lines toward the top of your `wp-config.php` file:

   define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com/wordpress');  // wordpress core files
   define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');               // address bar url

   // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
   ...
   *(do not include trailing slashes here - that would be configured elsewhere)*

Reference: [WP_SITEURL](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#blog-address-url) and [WP_HOME](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#wp-siteurl)

**NOTE: This is *confusing***
*(I really wish WordPress had Labeled the Settings similar to their php names,

such as `Wordpress Site Address` and `Home Page Address` or something more explicit like `location of WordPress Site core files` and `browser url to access WordPress home page`)*

```
`WP_SITEURL` <--> `site_url()` <--> `siteurl` <--> Wordpress Address <--> /wordpress   
`WP_HOME`    <--> `home_url()` <--> `home`    <--> Site Address      <--> /
```

#### Now Here is where it gets tricky !

***IF*** you defined those constants in your `wp-config.php` file, it *does not matter* what values you have in your database/settings page.
In fact, you will not be able to modify this value through the back end (it'll be greyed out). You can still modify in by editing your database, but doing so will have no effect on your site, while the constants exist in your wp-config file.

You config file **will not change** the values in your database (or hence you settings page).  Instead, your database/settings page values ***will be ignored***.  The values in wp-config override or take precedence over your database setting.

#**So... to wrap up (TLDR) :**

```
WP function  | wp_options. | WP constant  | what it represents       | WP Settings Label | Example     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
`site_url()` | `siteurl`   | `WP_SITEURL` | WordPress files location | WordPress Address | https://www.example.com/wordpress
`home_url()` | `home`      | `WP_HOME`    | browser address bar      | Site Address      | https://www.example.com
```

Where the value for a WP constant takes precedence over an wp_options/ WP Settings value.

The wp_options record value and the WP Settings value are the same.
Editing one, by definition edits the other.
It is just 2 different ways of accessing the same variable.

On the other hand, the WordPress Constants are unique and independent.
Internally, WordPress (PHP) constants override their db counterparts.
If a constant is defined in wp-config, it does *not* change the database.
But internally WordPress will always prefer/use its value *instead* of the db one.

Answer (score 9):

If you want WP installed in a directory but the site home on your domain root, you need to move the main index.php file out to your domain root and edit the require statement to point within your directory.

This process is outlined here: [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).

Comment: I always just use `home_url()` since i am on wp network mode. I have only given WordPress its own directory once and it just was not my liking. But i do however use the `wp_content_dir` on some sites.

Comment: I don't have any experience with multisite, so I'm not familiar how this stuff works in that situation. I prefer installing WP in a directory just to keep things clean and not clutter the root.

Comment: my file structure is probably one of the neatest ones around. `home/usr/public_html/site1` `home/usr/public_html/site2` and so on and then the `wp_content_dir` is usually on a cdn

Comment: if a WP install were the only thing there it would be fine, but I'm mostly working on other peoples servers with hundreds of files and directories littered about.

Comment: Is my understanding correct that site_url() and home_url() are the same, unless one sets up their wordpress install directory to be different than the root?

Answer (score 5):

The `site_url()` and `home_url()` functions are similar and can lead to confusion in how they work.

The `site_url()` function retrieves the value value for `siteurl` in the `wp_options` table  in your database.

This is the URL to the WordPress core files.
If your core files exist in a subdirectory `/wordpress` on your web server, the value would be `http://example.com/wordpress`.

The `home_url()` function retrieves the value for `home` in the `wp_options` table in your database.

This is the address you want people to visit to view your WordPress web site.

If your WordPress core files exist in `/wordpress`, but you want your web site URL to be `http://example.com` the home value should be `http://example.com`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question:

> Q: If that's correct, then can I get wordpress to return http://example.com/ ?

You can't, unless you take the [Giving WordPress its own directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) steps. Using this means you put WordPress core files into `/blog` or `/WordPress` and then the `index.php` into your root.

If you decide to put WordPress inside its own directory then you would use `home_url()` for going to `index.php` and `site_url()` for getting core files and such.

Refrences:
[Codex for `site_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url)
[Codex for `home_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url)
[Codex for Giving Wordpress Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

Answer (score 0):

Your first question it is responsed, but i think the easiest way to retrieve your root domain is with the function bloginfo('url'); also, bloginfo() have some others parameters to return , check the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/).

There's a get_bloginfo() too to check if you want to wrap the content into a var.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/265614)

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to get the site url without any sub-directories ( http://example.com/ instead of http://example.com/blog ), just use the backslash **/**

For example, if you type:

```
<a href="/">domain url</a>
```

It will create a link that goes to your domain

Comment: Thanks for participating.  Unfortunately, this does not answer the question posed by the OP.  There are many reasons why a person needs to use  the wordpress functions OP asks about. It is unlikely that OP simply wants to add link to their home page via html, such as by editing a post.  It is more likely, OP is editing a php theme file, or a plugin file.  In any case, they are working with php, not html. Finally, while OP *expected* a value without `/` for *this* site, on a different site, OP may *expect* a subdirectory to be returned.  It depends on the WP configuration for each site.