# Generate HTTPS Urls in multisite

Tags: multisite, ssl, https

I have a plugin that allow my users in multisite to generate simple urls like http://example.com/user/?my_url=2DD0B8183 but i want to include the https instead http ...

```
echo '<div>';
    echo '<div><input type="text" class="url" value="' .get_option('home'). '/?my_url=' . $download["code"] . '" onclick="this.select();" /></div>';
    exit();
  }
```

I tried

```
echo '<div><input type="text" class="url" value="https://' .get_blogaddress_by_id( $user_info->primary_blog ) . '?my_url=' . $download["code"] . '" onclick="this.select();" /></div>';
```

but i get `https://http://example.com/user/?my_url=C4785825B`

I have already forced ssl/https for entire my network via .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `get_option`, use [`home_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url) which will determine ...

> the appropriate protocol, "https" if `is_ssl()` and "http" otherwise. If
>   the `$scheme` argument is "http" or "https" the `is_ssl()` check is
>   overridden.

In fact, [`network_home_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/network_home_url) would be more appropriate since you are talking about Multisite.

Those [should return the same value](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1906) that you are trying the access in your code-- the `home` option key-- but with the appropriate protocol.

This may not be the [URL you want though](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/20294/21376).  You may want [`site_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) or the multisite equivalent, [`network_site_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/network_site_url).

Comment: @Ghinnersmee : yep. I used a function that returns the same address as `get_option('home')`, which you were trying to use, but with the appropriate protocol. What you needed was a different address altogether. I will update the answer for future visitors.