# How to request admin-ajax.php correctly when wordpress URL and site URL are different?

Tags: plugins, ajax, front-end, wp-config

When *site_url()* and *home_url()* are different, 
how a request should be directed to *admin-ajax.php* (both in front-end and admin)?
Using
A. `admin_url('wp-admin/admin-ajax.php')` 
or
B. `home_url('wp-admin/admin-ajax.php')`

Usually method A is used. However for some websites this request gives error 404 in front-end.
Method B does not work when wordpress is located in some sub-directory with respect to home_url().

Is there any method that works in all the cases when site_url() and home_url() are different?

See also here for the differences between site_url() and home_url():
[What's the difference between home_url() and site_url()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20294/whats-the-difference-between-home-url-and-site-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`admin_url()` should be used.

> However for some websites this request gives error 404 in front-end

`admin_url('admin-ajax.php')` should point to an actual file (`admin-ajax.php`), as such WordPress won't pass it through `index.php`, and so it *shouldn't* lead to the theme's 404 page. (Unless the file has been deleted).

... unless you have a `.htaccess` file which is redirecting the user away from `wp-admin` (for example)  (a recent client of mine had been doing this to whitelist IP addresses that could reach `wp-admin`).

Comment: Shouldn't you ommit `wp-admin/` in `admin_url` function?

Comment: @DmitriyDemir - yes, you're right. I've now corrected it.